# Why can't Visual Studio find a file in %path%?

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2015

I have created a batch file that runs upon successful build of a C# winforms project in Visual Studio 2015 (community edition update 3). In that batch file I want to ensure that certain other executables are not currently running.

To that end, the batch file contains lines similar to:

```
tskill notepad
```

When I build, the batch file executes but the output reads (in part):

```
'tskill' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

However I can run the batch file from a cmd prompt outside of Visual Studio and it works as expected (kills the executables specified with no reported errors).

I've tried ruling out obvious stuff: using the full path to `tskill`, making sure that `tskill` does in fact exist in the `c:\windows\system32` directory and that that directory is on the path.

I've also added `ECHO %path%` to the batch file to compare the path when called from VS as well as from a command line - the path is identical in both cases.

I've closed and re-started Visual Studio running as Administrator - same results.

So: **Why can't a batch file called from Visual Studio find c:\windows\system32\tskill.exe?**

(Note: I am aware that taskkill exists and is a similar utility, this question is not about alternatives to tskill but rather why VS cannot find it.)

**Edit**: to clarify questions from a commenter: the same error is reported whether I use the full path to the file or just the executable name. My current %path% system environment variable is 1564 characters in length (default max for windows 7 is 2047). The batch file works correctly when run as a non-elevated user outside Visual Studio from a command line.

**Edit 2**: performed the following test. 1) open notepad, 2) from elevated command prompt call tskill with full path to exe, 3) verify notepad no longer running.

[image]

**Edit 3**: I added the line `where tskill` to my batch file to see if it was calling the wrong file. From a command prompt, the batch file outputs: `C:\Windows\System32\tskill.exe`. From within Visual Studio that line outputs:  `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)`.

**Edit 4**: Per suggestion in the comments, I tried using the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015. While the %path% variable was longer, other behavior was the same (e.g., it could find tskill in c:\windows\system32 both from a batch and from the command line.)

Comment: How long (characters) is your PATH variable?  Do you understand that there is a system variable path and a user variable path?  "using the full path to tskill" - I assume when you provided the full path it works?  If you run `tskill` from a non-elevated command prompt, started by the same user, who started Visual Studio what happens?

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference between user environment variables and system environment variables. c:\windows\system32 is on the system environment's %path%, otherwise most of the operating system wouldn't run.

Comment: You should edit your question, so you address, the rest of my questions.

Comment: If you launch notepad, then in an elevated command prompt, call the full path to `tskill.exe` with an argument of notepad what happens?  Be sure you use the full filename `tskill.exe`.  Please update your question to include this information.  *I have a specific reason for you calling `tskill.exe` instead of just `tskill`.*

Comment: If you change the batch script to use `tskill.exe` instead of `tskill` what happens?  Just to clarify your calling `tskill` or `tskill.exe`, the reason I ask, there are two `tskill.exe` files in the system32 directory.  One is the application executable the other is a .MUI file.  The error you are getting is a classic sign of the wrong file being ran by mistake.

Comment: Same thing: "'tskill.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Comment: You might be able to get diagnose the problem if you manually launch the Visual Studio command prompt from a command prompt which will allow you to determine which environment variable your using.